# Windows Mapped Network Drives and VMWare

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, network-drive

We have an automated Windows builder server running as a VM under VMWare Workstation. For each build the VM is booted up, runs the build scripts via `vmrun` and is shutdown by the host.

This build process now needs to access a share drive and I can’t figure out how to get the mapped drive to connect on login. If I manually VNC onto the machine and login the mapped drive is fine. However when run via vmrun the mapped drive shows up as unavailable (Using `net use`). I’ve tried mapping the drive as part of the build script (rather than a persistent mapping set to reconnect at login) with `net use Z: \\drive\path /USER:domain\user password` which seems to create the mapping but just sits stuck on the call and doesn't return.

A bit of a niche question but is there any step I’m missing to get mapped drives to work via a headless login like this?

Comment: Try run `net use z: /delete /y` before `net use Z: \\drive\path /USER:domain\user password /P:Yes`